# In JIRA how can I have an agile board with multiple projects in it?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I wish an agile board that shows all tasks and epics from all projects in our jira install.

I have created the query

```
status = Open ORDER BY rank
```

when I create a scrum board based on this query it appears to work... however if I try and re- order an epic I get the error `A rank custom field ID must be specified for this operation.` and the click and drag functionality is disabled and shows the message `Ranking is disabled, as the Filter Query for this board is not ordered by Rank. Please check your filter configuration.`

The query is ordered by rank...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm well the more you know!

`status = Open ORDER BY Rank ASC`

easy

Comment: Looks like a bug in Jira. The query is case-insensitive, but the logic to determine if the ranking is enabled or not is case-sensitive.